# Counting instances of item in django template - table numbering

Tags: django, templates, templatetags

Is it possible to write a template tag that auto increments its' item number?

I have a series of manually generated HTML tables and I would like to be able to put a tag such as `{%table_number%}` below it and have it output like "Table 1", "Table 2" etc.

Can I pass a variable around somehow?

Comment: Can you use `forloop.counter`?

Comment: no they are scattered around the page and manually generated, not from a list